# How does Observable single work?

Tags: rx-java, observable

when I call .single() on an observable, its type is "Observable<`?>" and if I pass it to an other method I don't believe it has any mean of knowing that it has been singled. I don't think I understand fully how this works. Any idea?

Comment: Did you mean `Single s = observable.toSingle()`? I don't think this is published yet. It should be available at 1.0.13 or -SNAPSHOT

Comment: the .toSingle() method exists, but it doesn't return a Single, it returns an Observable.

Answer (score 4):

If the type isn't coming through you may need to either figure out why the signature isn't being carried through from the `Observable` calling it, or add it manually. So, for an `Observable` of type Foo:

```
myFooObservable.<Foo>single()
```

What single does is very similar to `limit(1)`, except that it will also throw an error if the upstream `Observable` does not output exactly 1 item when it completes (including 0 items).

In general when designing an `Observable` chain, consumers of an `Observable` should be designed as if they can handle zero or more values. It's true that another method doesn't know how many things will be emitted from the `Observable`. If you want a subscriber to require only a single element to be outputted, it should add `.single()` to the `Observable` it was handed before subscribing.

For example, let's say you're given a `getFoos` method:

```
Observable<Foo> getFoos();
```

For some reason (maybe it's a library, or codegen, or aliens) you have no access to the implementation of this, so you don't know how many things (if any) it will emit. If you want to enforce one and only one thing, you can do:

```
getFoos().single().subscribe(
    (foo) -> /* Do something with foo */,
    (error) -> /* Oh noes there was an error. Maybe it completed with no output? */);
```

This will limit it to one and only one thing, and throw an error if it completes without outputting a `Foo`, or if it tries to output a second `Foo`.

If the `getFoos` method had `single` on the `Observable` it handed you, it should be the responsibility of the author of `getFoos` to either:

1. Design and test it well enough that it will always emit only a single item. Probably the nicest approach for a consumer, API-wise, but this isn't always possible if external factors are involved, such as in #2...
2. *CLEARLY* document that it may not always emit a single item, and will throw you an error if it does not, so you can handle that error. Not my favorite approach, but on some things (say, a network response) it makes sense to declare that you may emit an error if not exactly one item is emitted. The [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library, for example, may throw `RetrofitError` exceptions if there are issues in any part of the network flow (I'm actually not positive this is clearly documented but given I figured it out pretty early on in using the app, I think it's easy enough to find). They're pretty good about making sure that things specific to the flow of the network request/response and parsing are wrapped in `RetrofitError`s so if some serious runtime error happens that is not part of that flow, it will fall through and crash (as it usually should in that instance, as those are probably programming errors or serious, unrecoverable system errors.)
3. Handle the error itself downstream of the `single` operator, possible by logging then emitting nothing if it ends up without a value. This is somewhere in the middle as far as my API tastes are concerned. Although it handles the error itself, there are legitimate cases for a consumer to want to handle and recover from errors, and this removes that ability. For example, one of my Android apps uses `retry` or `retryWhen` to figure out if a request should be retried, and I use various error transformers to apply those to set up different error handling behavior. Some requests I like to just log the error and move on. Others I like to do exponential backoff retries... Others I may want to do 1 or 2 immediate retries and then give up. Still others I might want to show a 'retry' UX button directly to the user.

If they don't meet at least 1 of those 3, I'd consider the API rather poorly designed, as the behavior is often going to be a surprise for consumers.

Some of this is a little abstract since I don't know your actual use case, so I'll be happy to clarify individual aspects of it if you have followup questions.

Comment: This answer is based on the `.single` call on `Observable`s. Based on some of your other open questions, it seems you may have been at least partially asking about the experimental `Single` class. The main difference there is that `.single` makes an `Observable` that only emits one or an error, where `Single` also gives you the type to enforce that. I think the API design issues still apply either way.